# How to reduce the computation time for an R program

Tags: r, time, prediction, computation

I am performing prediction on time series data but I am struggling with reducing the computation time. This is the code sample. So the code actually predicts temperature for different monitoring stations. For 134 stations, it takes like 10 minutes on my computer. I was thinking if there is a way to reduce the overall computation time.

The sample data looks like this. There are total 134 stations and the observation is done for 2 months.

```
date              station1        station2      station3         station4
18/01/2017 0:00     36.8           36.25           27.4            25.75
19/01/2017 0:00     30.71428571    34.6            29.4           22.33333333
20/01/2017 0:00     38.75          40.33333333     30.16666667    29.33333333
21/01/2017 0:00     40.83333333    40.33333333     31.2 3         2.25

dat1 <-read.csv("smart.csv")
library(forecast)
attach(dat1)
library(forecastHybrid)
ptm <- proc.time()
result<-data.frame(auto=0,nnetar=0)
for(i in 2:135) {
   temp.ts <-ts(dat1[i])
   train = temp.ts[1:600]
   test = temp.ts[601:620]

   hm3 <- hybridModel(train, weights = "equal", errorMethod = "MASE", models = 
"an")
   accuracy(hm3,individual = TRUE)
   hForecast <- forecast(hm3, h = 1) 
   result<-rbind(result,data.frame(auto=hForecast$pointForecasts[1],
                 nnetar=hForecast$pointForecasts[2]))
   fit_accuracy <- accuracy(hForecast, test)
}

proc.time()-ptm
write.csv(result, file= "xyz.csv")
```

Comment: It is easier to answer to question, when you give us some sample data. 
Nevertheless, the first thing I spot ist that you are growing your result dataframe in each step. I would initialize the final dimension before the loop (i.e. `results <- list(135)` and then store the result in that list. In the end you can transform it to one data.frame (i.e. `rbind.data.frame(results)` )

Comment: [Profile](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html) your code! If most of the time is spend in `hybridModel` there is no obvious and easy way to improve efficiency.

Comment: ... except parallelization, of course.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data, this will help a lot spotting your bottleneck

Comment: Thanks @kath for your suggestion. I will try that and see if it works.

Comment: @Roland , Yes, I tried parallelization, it does reduce the time but I was thinking there is any other way to do it.

Comment: @Antonis I have added sample data just to give u an idea how it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the sample I assume your data frame is something like

```
date<-seq(ymd_hm("2016-01-01 00:00"),ymd_hm("2017-09-11 00:00"),by="day")
station1<-runif(620)
station2<-runif(620)
station3<-runif(620)
station4<-runif(620)
dat1=data.frame(date,station1,station2,station3,station4)
```

if this is the case your code gives an error:

```
Error in testaccuracy(f, x, test, d, D) : 
  Not enough forecasts. Check that forecasts and test data match.
```

this error is caused by the last line of your loop:

```
fit_accuracy <- accuracy(hForecast, test)
```

since hForecast has length 1 and test length 20.

So I have written the following code that works and runs fast enough:

```
forecastStation<-function(data){
  temp=ts(data)
  train = temp[1:600,]
  test = temp[601:620,]
  #hm3 <- hybridModel(train, weights = "equal", errorMethod = "MASE", models = "an")
  arimaModel <-auto.arima(train)
  netModel=nnetar(train)
  accuracy(arimaModel,individual = TRUE);accuracy(netModel,individual = TRUE)
  arimaPredict <- forecast(arimaModel, 1)$mean[1]
  netPredict<- forecast(netModel, 1)$mean[1]
  return(data.frame(auto=arimaPredict,nnetar=netPredict))
}
result<-do.call("rbind",lapply(2:5,function(x) FUN=forecastStation(dat1[x])))
result$Station=colnames(dat1)[2:5]
```

the main difference with yours is that instead of using `hybridModel` function I use auto.arima and `nnetar` individually.

The result is a data frame in the form:

```
> result
       auto    nnetar  Station
1 0.4995727 0.4906344 station1
2 0.4907216 0.5045967 station2
3 0.5300489 0.5413126 station3
4 0.5021821 0.4951382 station4
```

for one step ahead forecasts. I am not sure whether you want 1 or 2 steps ahead. If the second is the case change the function to:

```
forecastStation<-function(data){
  temp=ts(data)
  train = temp[1:600,]
  test = temp[601:620,]
  #hm3 <- hybridModel(train, weights = "equal", errorMethod = "MASE", models = "an")
  arimaModel <-auto.arima(train)
  netModel=nnetar(train)
  accuracy(arimaModel,individual = TRUE);accuracy(netModel,individual = TRUE)
  arimaPredict <- forecast(arimaModel, 20)$mean[1:20]
  netPredict<- forecast(netModel, 20)$mean[1:20]
  return(data.frame(auto=arimaPredict,nnetar=netPredict))
}
```

hope this helps